# How to Identify which div in a sequence with the same class was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom-events

I have two arrays:

```
codes=[code1, code2, code3];
quantities=[23, 67, 87];
```

and this HTML

```
<div id='cart_body'></div>
```

and this script

```
Delete=function(){

}

document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML='';
    cart_text='';
    emp='<div class="close_button" onClick='Delete()'>x</div>';
    open_span='<span class="close_span ">';
    close_span='</span>';
    elf='<br class="none"/>';
    for(i=0; i<product_codes.length; i++){
//the two lines directly below this line are actually one continuous line
        cart_text+=(open_span+codes[i]+"  
        (x"+quantities[i]+")"+close_span+emp+elf);
    }


    document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML=cart_text;
```

and this css:

```
.close_button{
display: inline-block;
background-color: grey;
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
border-radius: 6px;
}
span{

display: inline-block;
}
```

The purpose of this script is to write lines of text. Each line has one code, and one quantity, as well as a div. The div also has some styling that makes in into a circular button, but that bit is irrelevant.

My questions are these: What can I write so that the delete function can detect which div in the class "close_button" triggered the function?

BASED ON THAT, the function needs to delete that line of text (the line that contains the div that was clicked, the code, and the quantity), as well as delete those two items (the code and quantity) from their respective arrays.

How can I do this?

If I'm not being clear enough feel free to ask :)

P.S. (answers with a working fiddle would be especially appreciated) ;-)

P.P.S. please regular JavaScript only. No libraries or frameworks, please.

Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/uhwLg8ss/)

Click the button that says click me. In the actual code, I do not know how many items there will be in the arrays, but there will be an identical amount in each. Like I said, I need any of the small circular buttons, when clicked, to delete itself and all text on the same line, as well as the items in the arrays that the text on that line represents.

Comment: Before you look into your issue you should fix the problems with the code you provided. `onClick='delete()'` needs to be `onClick="delete()"` so you don't escape the starting single quotes. Also `delete` is a taken keyword in JavaScript, you need to use something different such as `Delete`. Along with other problems, it would be convient if you could give us a starting fiddle or snippet with the working base code.

Comment: Right, rest of code is not runing well...first you need to fix it.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek working on it right now.

Comment: *Delete* would be better as *deleteDiv* or similar. You can pass a reference to the div in the listener using *this*.: `... onclick="deleteDiv(this)" ...`.

Comment: alright @RobG the fiddle is here

Comment: @SunilMadaan fiddle is added to the questiom

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek added a fiddle to the question

Comment: @Leshy–code should be reduced to a [*minimum that exhibits the issue*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and posted here. Linking to code elsewhere means that it may not be available in future so the question and answer become useless. You can also [*run code snippets in questions and answers*]( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***What can I write so that the delete function can detect which div in the class "close_button" triggered the function?***

To do this I would first recommend having each element in a `<div>` rather than a `<span>` and a separate `<div>`. Then we could just remove the parent:

```
cart_text+= "<div>"+(open_span+codes[i]+"   (x"+quantities[i]+")"+close_span+emp+elf)+"</div>";
```

To remove the parent you can do `item.parentNode.remove();`, where you can pass the element as `this` in the `onclick` event:

```
<div class="close_button" onclick="deleteItem(this)">x</div>
```

And the function to remove the element:

```
deleteItem = function(item) {
    item.parentNode.remove();
}
```

[**Here is a fiddle example.**](https://jsfiddle.net/uhwLg8ss/2/)

***What about the item in the array?***

To do this we need to get the text from our element, remove the text that has `(x[Number])`, then trim that. From there we need to go through the array and find the element with the matching text and remove that element from our array. To do that I made a separate function for removing an element from an array:

```
function removeTextFromArray(array, text){
    for (var i=array.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (array[i] === text) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            quantities.splice(i, 1); // Removes from quantities at same position
            return array;
        }
    }
}
```

And to get the text, and remove the stuff we don't want in that text:

```
deleteItem = function(item) {
    item.parentElement.remove();
    // Gets the text in the close_span class of the parent div  
    var textInNode = item.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("close_span")[0].innerHTML;
    // Removes the items in (...) and trims the string.
    textInNode = textInNode.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "").trim();
    // Takes the string and removes it from the codes array
    codes = removeTextFromArray(codes, textInNode);  
}
```

[**Here is a Fiddle Example of that.**](https://jsfiddle.net/uhwLg8ss/5/)

Comment: Note that *parentElement* is introduced in DOM 4 which is not yet a standard, therefore it may not be supported widely. The alternative *parentNode* has been around since DOM 1 so is universally supported (and less to type). ;-)

Comment: @RobG Ah, thanks. I'll use that instead, I tend to like using the newest things :).

Comment: It would be nice if the specifications included a note for when features were introduced and last modified, especially as many are becoming "living" standards. It would help greatly in determining whether a particular feature might be supported or not (support matrices are a good idea but aren't user friendly and require constant updating).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks! this is exactly what i'm looking for. However, I also need the function to delete the corresponding quantity to the code that is being deleted. Can you add that and let me know?

Comment: @Leshy Alright added it :). Assuming they will both be in the same positions. If they are it may be a better idea to group them as an array of objects so the text and the quantities are at in the same place.

Comment: Note that `item.parentNode.remove();` will fail in IE (and plenty of older browsers) since it doesn't support the *remove* method on elements. Far more compatible is `item.parentNode.removeChild(item)`.

Answer (score 0):

The function would be better named as *deleteDiv* or more generically as *deleteElement* and can be use to delete any element.

You can pass a reference to the element that called the listener using *this*:

```
emp = '<div class="close_button" onClick="deleteElement(this)">x</div>';
```

then the function can be:

```
function deleteElement(el) {
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

Comment: will check in the morning am going to bed now.

Comment: what about removing the values from the arrays?

Comment: what about the arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is all working. Just click Run

```js
product_codes=['code1', 'code2', 'code3'];
quantities=[23, 67, 87];

function deleteIt(e){
  e.parentNode.remove();
}

document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML='';
cart_text='';
emp='<div class="close_button" onclick="deleteIt(this)">x</div>';
open_span='<span class="close_span ">';
close_span='</span>';
elf='<br class="none"/>';
for(i=0; i<product_codes.length; i++){
    cart_text+='<div>'+(open_span+product_codes[i]+"(x"+quantities[i]+")"+close_span+emp+elf)+'</div>';
}

document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML=cart_text;
```

```css
.close_button{
display: inline-block;
margin:4px;
  position:relative;
background-color: red;
color:blue;
border:1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 50%;
padding:2px 7px;

cursor:default;  
 
}
.close_button:hover{
border: 1px solid blue;
}
span{

display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='cart_body'></div>
```

Comment: note that I renamed "delete" since that word is reserved in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
x = document.getElementsByClassName("e");

for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].onclick = function() {deleteIt(this)}
  
}

function deleteIt(x) {

    x.style.display = "none"
    
  }
```

```html
<div class=e>Some text 0</div>
<div class=e>Some text 1</div>
<div class=e>Some text 2</div>
<div class=e>Some text 3</div>
<div class=e>Some text 4</div>
<div class=e>Some text 5</div>
```

Edited for pure JS, thanks to this post [Applying onClick to Element Array in a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498187/applying-onclick-to-element-array-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: This doesnn't delete the code fro the arrays, though, which is essential to the question

Answer (score 0):

As you want here is the following solution without using any frameowrk or library.

HTML:

```
<div id='cart_body'></div>
<button OnClick='myfunction()'>Click me</button>
```

JS:

```
    codes=['hi', 'random text', 'lorem ipsum'];
quantities=[1, 45, 32];
 deleteDiv = function(e) {
    console.log(e);

     var code_name_str = e.currentTarget.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText.split('(')[0];

     var code_name = code_name_str.substring(0, code_name_str.length - 1);
     var code_index = codes.indexOf(code_name);
     if (code_index > -1) {
        codes.splice(code_index, 1);
     }
         console.log(codes);
         var code_quantity_str = e.currentTarget.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText.split('(')[1];

     var code_quantity = code_quantity_str.substring(0, code_quantity_str.length - 1);
     var quantity_index = quantities.indexOf(parseInt(code_quantity));
     if (quantity_index > -1) {
        quantities.splice(quantity_index, 1);
     }
      console.log(quantities);
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.parentElement.removeChild(e.currentTarget.parentNode);
}
myfunction = function(){
document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML='';
    open_div = '<div>'
        cart_text='';
        emp='<div id="sam" class="close_button"  onclick="deleteDiv(event)">x</div>';
        open_span='<span class="close_span">';
        close_span='</span>';
        elf='<br class="none"/>';
    close_div = '</div>'
        for(i=0; i<codes.length; i++){
            cart_text+=(open_div+open_span+codes[i]+"   ("+quantities[i]+")"+close_span+emp+elf+close_div);
        }
        document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML=cart_text;
}
```

CSS:

```
#cart_body{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
span{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
    .close_button{
    border:  1px solid black;
    width: 12px;
    height:  12px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align:  center;
    line-height: 11px;
    background-color: lightGrey;
    display:  inline-block;
    margin-left:  20px;
    }
body{
    font-size: 12px;

}
.close_button:hover{
    color: red;
    border: 2px solid red;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Fiddle Link:

https://jsfiddle.net/uhwLg8ss/4/